# WHERE condition avoids full table scan somehow

Tags: mysql, database-performance

When evaluating the performance of creating a `SQL` view query, I noticed a significant improvement in performance when adding a `WHERE` clause at the end. The output difference is not much (~3% less rows).

e.g.

```
SELECT x,y,z  
FROM (multiple table joins/sub queries)
```

vs

```
SELECT x,y,z  
FROM (multiple table joins/sub queries)  
WHERE x >= 0 (x is not indexed)
```

Checking the execution plans, it seems that the biggest difference is the `WHERE` condition avoids a full table scan which explains the difference in speed. Why is that?

EDIT: Screenshots showing execution operation with WHERE condition vs without

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the execution plan that "avoids the full table scan". What operation does it perform instead of `all`?

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say?

Comment: Added screenshots

Comment: Where the heck did you get that form of output?  Please provide the full query, its `EXPLAIN`, _and_ `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  Be sure to qualify each column with the table it comes from.  It _may_ make a _big_ difference as to which table `x` comes from, even if not indexed.

Answer (score 1):

(Not enough info, even with the screenshots, to intelligently reply.  But I can make a guess...)

When faced with `JOIN(s)`, the Optimizer often (but *not always*) uses these rules to decide which table to start with:

- Start with the table that seems to have the best `WHERE` filtering.  That *may* have led it to pick the table with `x` in it.  Even it that were a full table scan, picking that table may be better.
- Start with the 'smallest' table.

Note:  It scans the 'first' table; for each row in that table, it reaches into the 'next' table, then the next, etc.  The Optimizer is free to reorder the tables as it sees fit (within constraints such as `LEFT`).

In reality, the later incarnations of the Optimizer use a "cost-based" analysis.  However, the above two 'rules' are what effectively happens.

Also, the Optimizer may be misled by statistics, or lack of such, on which it bases the query plan.